# Parse.com REST API method $in doesn't seem to be working

Tags: parse-platform

This returns 0 results:

```
https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Photo?where={"event_id":{"$in":[383,391,392]},"approved":"1"}&order=-createdAt
```

But this returns all results for event 383 as expected:

```
https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Photo?where={"event_id":"383","approved":"1"}&order=-createdAt
```

Should that first query return the same as the second AND any photos found for events 391 or 392?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Heard from Parse.com dev who pointed out that "event_id" is a string and the first query above I'm passing in an array of numbers when an array of strings is expected.

Comment: I was doing the exact same thing. You should award this as the correct answer.